Edit right click function of a link in WebView
How can I edit the right click function to call a specific function, maybe like an add tab function inside of a custom web view.
Here is the code that I tried so far:
struct WKWebViewRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        return webView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        uiView.load(request)
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate {
    let parent: WKWebViewRepresentable

    init(_ parent: WKWebViewRepresentable) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.targetFrame == nil {
            // New tab request detected, print message and cancel navigation
            print("New tab request detected")
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}

When I right click a link, then it still opens in Safari, so I don't really know what I am doing wrong here.
